# LibGDX Actor doesn't perform Action

Tags: java, libgdx, action, actor

I cannot get my Card Actor to perform an Action(i have no problem with adding and performing actions on Images and Textures).This is my Card.class code :

```
public class Card extends Actor {
final float CARD_WIDTH = 500 * cardScale;
final float CARD_HEIGHT = 726 * cardScale;
String face, suit;
public Texture cardFace = new Texture("CardTextures/" + face + suit + ".png");

Vector2 position = new Vector2(0, 0);

public Card(String face, String suit, Vector2 position) {
    this.face = face;
    this.suit = suit;
    this.position = position;
    setBounds(position.x, position.y, CARD_WIDTH, CARD_HEIGHT);
}

public Card(String face, String suit) {
    this.face = face;
    this.suit = suit;
    this.position = position;
    setBounds(position.x, position.y, CARD_WIDTH, CARD_HEIGHT);
}

@Override
public void act(float delta) {
    super.act(delta);

}

@Override
public void draw(Batch batch, float alpha) {
    batch.draw(cardFace, position.x, position.y, cardFace.getWidth() * cardScale, cardFace.getHeight() * cardScale);
}

public String getFace() {
    return face;
}

public String getSuit() {
    return suit;
}

public void setCardPosition(Vector2 position) {
    this.position = position;

}

public void setCardFaceTexture() {
    cardFace = new Texture(("CardTextures/" + this.getFace() + this.getSuit() + ".png"));
}
```

}

Whenever I try to perform an action with a Card Actor it doesn't work. Even when I place the actions in the Create() method it doesn't work. I tried this :

```
moveAction = new MoveToAction();
    moveAction.setPosition(300f, 0f);
    moveAction.setDuration(10f);
    Card card = new Card("two", "spades");
    card.addAction(moveAction);
```

This is my render method :

```
 @Override
public void render() {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    stage.act(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
    stage.draw();
    updateActorBounds();

    camera.update();

    batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

    batch.begin();
    font.draw(batch, "FPS:" + Gdx.graphics.getFramesPerSecond(), TABLE_WIDTH / 2 - 65, TABLE_HEIGHT / 2 - 10);
    batch.end();
}
```

Comment: did you add your card to the stage?

Comment: I did and it gets drawn on the stage, it recieves touch input , i can change its position based on touch input ,but i cant get it to move with an Action(I wanted it to move smoothly)

Comment: where do you update your Cards position variable? You call act, which calls super.act() method and in your overriden draw method you use batch.draw(cardFace, position.x, position.y, cardFace.getWidth() ... but position.x and .y are updated when? the action acts on the Actor's position, (try putting the getX() and getY() methods in your overriden draw to see if there is a difference)

Comment: I see now . Putting getX and getY worked . But now I have another problem. I have all my cards in an array (Card[] deck= new Card[52]). And they are initialised as so :  deck[0] = new Card("two", "spades") ect ....when i try deck[0].addAction(moveAction); it just doesn't work

Comment: You gotta create a new action for each one. You should create your actions with Action.moveToAction instead of new MoveToAction. That way the actions you use are pooled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Card` is using its own position `Vector2 position`. When you add a `MoveAction` to your `Card`, the action accesses and mutates the `x` and `y` variables within the `Actor` class - not yours. This means, if you would like your `Card` to show up where the actions says it should, instead of drawing at `position.x, position.y`, you need to draw at `getX(), getY()`.

Your constructor will look like:

```
public Card(String face, String suit, Vector2 position) {
    this.face = face;
    this.suit = suit;
    setBounds(position.x, position.y, CARD_WIDTH, CARD_HEIGHT);
}
```

Your draw method will look like:

```
@Override
public void draw(Batch batch, float alpha) {
    batch.draw(cardFace, getX(), getY(), cardFace.getWidth() * cardScale, cardFace.getHeight() * cardScale);
}
```